# jQuery if radio button is selected

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of code here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=MMERGE8]:radio").click(function () {
        var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
        alert(checked);
    });
});
```

I am trying to check if a radio button is checked or not and store that into a variable. But when i run this code checked returns as undefined. Why?

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML. You probably want to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: When you click on a radio button it will always be checked.

Comment: You can use `$(this).is(":checked")`

Comment: Maybe you should use `this.value`, so you know which of the radio buttons is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the click event you can just use this.value to find out which value is selected in the group as the click event is always going to set the radio as checked for the radio group.

```
$('[name="test"]').click(function () {
    alert(this.value)
});
```

if you were trying to get the value from another event you would use a selector for the group and get the checked item.

```
$('#getValue').click(function () {
    alert($('[name="test"]:checked').val());
});
```

Examples here...
http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/7hb71jga/